# Updating list in shared preferences

Tags: android, gson, sharedpreferences

in my android app I stored a list of a custom class List via gson in shared preferences.
Now my problem is that I changed code in the class WORD and I have no idea how to apply this to the current list in "shared preferences" of the old version of my app. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the relevant code and what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. my work around was to surround your error with a `try catch` and create a new list of objects out of the old ones. Then save your newly created list so it doesnt happen again.

```
          try {
                                        if (object.getNewMethod().equals("")) {
                                           wontHappenBecauseError();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e) {
    
        //create new arraylist to save
                                        ArrayList<Object> updatedObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
    
        //loop through old objects
                                       for(Object oldObject: oldObjectsList){
    
        //for each, add an object to the new list from the attributes of the old list
                                           updatedObjectsList.add(new Object(oldObject.getAttribute, oldObject.getOtherAttribute);
}
    
    
        //save the new and improved list so it doesnt happen again
                                           Gson gson = new Gson();
                                           Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Object>>(){}.getType();
                                           String json = gson.toJson(updatedObjectList,type);
                                           editor.putString("ObjectList",json);
    editor.commit();
                                       }
```